# a href link used as tooltip not working well

Tags: jsp, struts2

I am using `a href link` to use as `tool tip` for `struts2 tags`. But the problem is due to href link, it starts to behave weird for textfields and select struts2 tag.

```
<a  style="color: inherit" href="#" title="<s:text name="tooltips.key"/>">
    <s:textfield key="key" name="myKey" theme="simple"></s:textfield>
</a>
```

For textfields, I can't move around my cursore in the textboxs once I select insides them.

For select tag, I can't select the texts from drop down list.

And it keeps appending # to the end of the action once I click on that href wrapped struts2 tag.

Answer (score 1):

`<a>` tag should not be used as a tooltip.

I strongly suggest you go with CSS or JS for this.

Declare an hidden field with "`tooltips.key`" value, then show it on `:hover` of your `<s:textfield>`

You can use an helper like this: http://csstooltip.com/